# Google Drive File not set expiration time permissions

Tags: php, google-drive-api

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();

$newPermission->setEmailAddress($value); 
$newPermission->setExpirationTime('2018-07-13T16:00:00+05:30');
$newPermission->setType($type);
$newPermission->setRole($role);
```

my drive storage not storing  ExpirationTime

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions ,  The time at which this permission will expire (RFC 3339 date-time). Expiration times have the following restrictions:

    They can only be set on user and group permissions
    The time must be in the future
    The time cannot be more than a year in the future

Comment: @arunp9294 I'm using RFC 3339 date-time, permission is setting for user as read only permission, but expiration time is not setting.

Comment: How are you settings the permission? If possible add that code also to the question.

Comment: @arunp9294 I've created function written below to insert a permission: 
 function insertPermission($service,$fileId,$value,$type,$role) {
 $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();

 $newPermission->setEmailAddress($value); 
 $newPermission->setExpirationTime('2018-07-13T16:00:00+05:30');
 $newPermission->setType($type);
 $newPermission->setRole($role);

 try {
  return $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
 return NULL;
}

Answer (score 1):

There is some minor changes in v3. Check out this links https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing
https://gist.github.com/bshaffer/9bb2cdccd315880ab52f#file-drive-php-L954

```
 insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role) { 
        $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
            'type' => $type,
            'role' => $role,
            'emailAddress' => $value,
            'expirationTime' => '2018-08-18T16:00:00+05:30'
        ));
        try { 
            $created =  $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission); 
            $permissionsId = $created->id;
            $updatedPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
                'role' => $role,
                'expirationTime' => '2018-08-18T16:00:00+05:30'
            ));
            $updated =  $service->permissions->update($fileId, $permissionsId , $updatedPermission, array(
                'fields' => 'id, expirationTime'
            )); 
            $expirationTime = $updated->expirationTime;
            echo "expirationTime : " . $expirationTime;
        } catch (Exception $e) { 
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage(); 
        }
        return NULL; 
    }
```

Comment: @vidya devi I didn't check if the above code works. Please update the code once its start working.

Comment: @arun9294 I'm using same code, I'm not getting any error but expiration time is also not setting

Comment: did you change the expirationTime? expirationTime' => '2018-07-13T16:00:00+05:30' won't work now.  And whats the response you got?  expirationTime should be future date. 'expirationTime' => '2018-08-19T16:00:00+05:30'

Comment: I'm using future date only like '2018-07-17T16:00:00+05:30'. I'm getting one JSON data in that expiration time = null. In google Drive expiration time is not setting for file.

Comment: expirationTime  datetime  The time at which this permission will expire (RFC 3339 date-time). Expiration times have the following restrictions:

    They can only be set on user and group permissions
    The time must be in the future
    The time cannot be more than a year in the future
.  Read here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions . Whats the value of '$type' ?

Comment: given type value as user $type=>user

Comment: @vidya I checked by creating . In the response it won't return. You can get  the permission to check if the expiryTime is set. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get   . You have to set 'expirationTime' in  fields .

Comment: I have updated the code with update command. Created command doesn't return or set expiryTime from what I read from some of the posts (either a bug or functionality yet to provide) . By update command expiry time was getting set and was able to retreive also. I didn't check the php code which posted above. I checked directly in the gdrive api playground (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update). I hope the code above with syntax fixes should work